# Nested For Loop Problems in C

Tags: c, cs50

Im trying to understand and figure out how to make a pyramid going left to right.

I have the computer asking for the height, it is only 1-8

Im trying to make that pyryamid look something like this depending on the height

I have a squared being made.
Heres the code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int getHeight;

    do
    {
        //asks height
        getHeight = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    //If the height is greater then 8 then ask for the Height again
    while(getHeight > 8);


    //
    for(int row = 0; row < getHeight; row++)
    {
        for(int colums = 0; colums < getHeight; colums++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}**
```

Comment: Take some time to think about it a little. Perhaps use pen and paper to draw it out and figure out an algorithm. For example, for the first row, how many columns should you print?

Comment: Perhaps you should add an example of what you want the output to look like too? Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74511617/edit) the question and put one example in there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your inner loop is wrong. It iterates up to `getHeight` but should only iterate up to (and including) `row`:

```c
for(int row = 0; row < getHeight; row++)
{
    for(int colums = 0; colums <= row; colums++)
    { //                       ^^^^^^
```

Each iteration of the outer loop will increase `row`. The inner loop will make one more iteration over `colums` every time `row` increases.

Output if the user enters `8`:

```
#            // row 0, columns 0-0
##           // row 1, columns 0-1
###          // row 2, columns 0-2
####         // row 3, columns 0-3
#####        // row 4, columns 0-4
######       // row 5, columns 0-5
#######      // row 6, columns 0-6
########     // row 7, columns 0-7
```

Comment: Oh ok, was thrown by your `colums <= row` as if OP had wrong limits.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see. My code will make a "pyramid" (sort of). If it has the correct shape or not, I can't say. :)

Comment: Yes, I had intended to comment under the question : Please show the expected output. It could be a triangle slanted left, or right, or a symmetric pyramid with space separators to align each row.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the expected solutions

Height 3

#
##
###

Comment: @Jordan If this shape is not what you want, just edit your question and put the expected shape in there.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The solution does work but could you go in depth a bit more? im extremly new to coding and im not understanding it completley

Comment: @Jordan if you format the pattern "as code" (like Ted did) that will show the correct spacing and alignment.

Comment: @Jordan I added an explanation to the answer.